# Process (robocopy) not closing

Tags: c#, process

I use Robocopy to move files from one computer to another. I am using the code below:

```
    public void MoveRecords()
    {
        try
        {
            using (Process Robocopy = new Process())
            {
                Robocopy.StartInfo.FileName = this._commandPromptCommand;
                Robocopy.StartInfo.Arguments = this._commandPromptString;
                Robocopy.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                Robocopy.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                Robocopy.Start();

                DateTime StartTime = DateTime.Now;

                if (Robocopy.WaitForExit(AppSettings.MaxMoveOperationWaitTime))
                {
                    TimeSpan ElapsedTime = DateTime.Now - StartTime;
                    this._logRobocopyExitCode(Robocopy.ExitCode, ElapsedTime);
                }
                else
                {
                    Logger.Write(string.Format("Timeout occured for the move operation of {0} from {1}. ", _getFilesInProgress(), this._ip), EventLogEntryType.Error);
                    Robocopy.Kill();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.Write(ex, EventLogEntryType.Error);
        }
    }
```

When i look at to task manager i saw many "Console Window Host" and "Microsoft Robocopy" processes. You can see the situation from the screenshot below.

[image]

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: What value is contained in `AppSettings.MaxMoveOperationWaitTime`?

Comment: 250000 but this is not an important point!

Comment: And what are `_commandPromptCommand` and `_commandPromptString` set to? Is it possible that the RoboCopy instance is waiting for user input? Perhaps you should set `CreateNoWindow` to `false` and watch what it's doing.

Comment: You could connect a debugger to robocopy to see what it is waiting for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you need a "process.close".  Following is an example I use in VB.NET:

```
            ' Create an instance of the command prompt and run RoboCopy for the current network location.
            Try
                pCmdPrompt = New Process
                With pCmdPrompt
                    .StartInfo.FileName = Environment.SystemDirectory & "\RoboCopy.exe"                         ' Resides in System32
                    .StartInfo.Arguments = strDirSrc & " " & strDirDest & strRoboCopyArg & strLogFileFullName
                End With
                pCmdPrompt.Start()              ' Begin RoboCopy
                pCmdPrompt.WaitForExit()        ' Wait for RoboCopy to complete.  Needed in order to obtain DateEnd for Duration details for log.
                pCmdPrompt.Close()              ' RoboCopy completed. Close.
                pCmdPrompt = Nothing            ' Clean up for next loop.

                ' RoboCopy occurred w/o exception. Set string that will be used for log entry.
                strDetailsDone = "Success"

            Catch ex As Exception
                ' Exception occurred during RoboCopy.  Set string that will be used for log entry.
                '   Continue w/ processing - do NOT halt application.
                strDetailsDone = "Exception occurred: " & ex.Message & vbCrLf & ex.StackTrace
                If pCmdPrompt IsNot Nothing Then pCmdPrompt = Nothing
            End Try
```